# How to validate flux elements that are later buffered?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, flux, buffering

I have the following code which throws error and no flux elements is "processed" so printed on the screen:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux.just("A", "B", "Z", "D")
                .flatMap(Test::validate)
                .collectList()
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Mono<String> validate(String s) {
        return "Z".equals(s) ? Mono.error(new RuntimeException("It's Z!")) : Mono.just(s);
    }
}
```

But let's say I want to improve performance with buffering and change main method to:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux.just("A", "B", "Z", "D")
                .flatMap(Test::validate)
                .buffer(2)
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
```

This time error is thrown as well but 2 first elements belonging to first buffer are "processed" and displayed on the screen. **How to make program behaving like in the first case
where no flux elements is processed and keep buffering?** This is ilustration of much more complex problem of mine. Introducing buffering gives big performance boost but if one element in the flux fails to validate, some elements are saved to the database while nothing should be saved.

Comment: The behaviour in the first case is "accidental". flatMap launches concurrently tasks, and break guarantee of ordering. It may very well have displayed 1 or 3 elements before failing, instead of 0. From your question, I think what you want is a **Transaction**. But Reactor itself does not offer any transaction operator. You will have to look at how your database driver (jdbc, r2dbc, jpa, jooq, etc.) manage transactions.

Comment: My db is DynamoDB and it has no transaction support in the way as relational databases have. TransactWriteItems is not an option in my case.

Comment: In the first case _buffer_ is the whole flux, and it stops with an error because the flux fails to complete. The second with two element buffer, it emits the first part, then it stops with the same error too. To me, both behave the same way, you just define a different number of elements until it stops.